# How to disable CS0168 warning about unused exception variable in catch block?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I always add a variable in my catch structure:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Even when I don't use `e` in the catch block.
I do so because I don't know how to get the exception (and its detail) if I enter an "anonymous" catch while debugging.

```
catch { /* ...how to get the exception from here ?... */ }
```

If the exception is not used in the catch block I get a CS0168 warning: "variable e is unused"

I know how to globally disable CS0168 (or locally) but I'd rather not have to do so because it could hide useful messages too.

I'd rather not have to add fake code in the block to use the exception so that it does not raise the warning.

I'd rather not edit/remove the parameter accordingly to its (not) usage in the catch block just to remove the warning.

Ideally I want to know how to get the instance of the exception when debugging.

Comment: If you aren't using the `e` variable, you can write your catch as `catch (Exception)`

Comment: My probleme was to highlight the variable to look at its values. Using catch (Exception) won't help here (unless I'm missing something). Pseudo variable works fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to get the instance of the exception in the debugger while you are
in a `catch { ... }` block, you can use a [pseudovariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables).

Just open the Watch window and add `$exception`.

You can use this pseudovariable in any type of `catch` block to get the instance of the exception.

Answer (score 6):

You can you #pragma Directive, this will disable the warning message.
and you can restore it back too(like in the below code), which is advisable.

```
#pragma warning disable CS0168 // The variable 'e' is declared but never used
catch (Exception e)
#pragma warning restore CS0168 // The variable 'e' is declared but never used
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you but disabling the warning locally feels a little too verbose for me.